# Prove convexity of the given function on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

$f:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is  given by 
$$f(x)=\mbox{max}\{  (z_1-x_1)^{+},  (z_2-x_2)^{+}, ..., (z_3-x_3)^{+} \}$$
where  $x=(x_2,x_2,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and  $z = (z_1,z_2,..,z_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n$  and 
$(z_i-x_i)^{+}=\mbox{max}\{ z_i-x_i,0 \}$.

Prove that $f(x)$ is convex for any fix $z\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

This is $f(x)=\max\{z_1-x_1,z_2-x_2,\cdots, z_n-x_n,0\}$. Supremum of a family, finite or otherwise, of convex functions is convex, and affine maps (meaning, maps in the form $g(x)=\langle b,x\rangle +\alpha$) are convex.